# Xamarin ios i want to get first row automatically from UIPickerView without selection

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have two UIPickerViews and I want to automatically select the first row from UIPickerView1 to then populate data in UIPickerView2.

Currently when I start a app I have to select an item in UIPickerView1 populate data in UIPickerView2.

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();

    this.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromPatternImage(UIImage.FromFile("drawable/BackGro1.png"));

    Selling.WebServiceDB ws = new Selling.WebServiceDB();
    ws.LevelDataListCompleted += Ws_LevelDataListCompleted;
    ws.LevelDataListAsync();
}

private void Ws_LevelDataListCompleted(object sender, Selling.LevelDataListCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Result.ToString().Equals("0"))
    {

    }
    else
    {
        List<String> List = new List<String>();
        foreach (var item in e.Result)
        {
            List.Add(item.LevelNameA);
        }
        var LevelFill = new LevelFill(List);
        spinlvl3.Model = LevelFill;
        Globals.Globlvlname = LevelFill.SelectedColor;
        Selling.WebServiceDB ws2 = new Selling.WebServiceDB();
        LevelFill.ColorChanged += (Sender, N) =>
        {
            Globals.Globlvlname = LevelFill.SelectedColor;
            ws2.MajorAListCompleted += Ws2_MajorAListCompleted;
            ws2.MajorAListAsync(Globals.Globlvlname);
        };
    }
}

class LevelFill : UIPickerViewModel
{
    List<string> list;
    public event EventHandler ColorChanged;
    public String SelectedColor { get; private set; }   

    public LevelFill(List<string> list)
    {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public override void Selected(UIPickerView pickerView, nint row, nint component)
    {
        var color = list[(int)row];
        SelectedColor = color;
        ColorChanged?.Invoke(null, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select the value of UIPickerView, you can call the following method:

> public virtual void Select (nint row, nint component, bool animated);

Component here means column in the picker. By default UIPickerView will have 1 component set unless you specify other value inside `GetComponentCount()` in your UIPickerViewModel.

In your case, if your list of color is having 10 rows and you want to preselect the 5th row. You can just call:

> pickerView.Select(4, 0, true);